# Incompatible types "True = Sant" for boolean comparison when running Excel in different language?

Tags: excel, vba

This line works on my Excel 2013 when it is set to English:

```
If Sheets("Hämtningar").PivotTables("Hamtningar").PivotFields("strFacilityNo").PivotItems(i).Visible = True Then
```

However when I set Excel to Swedish I get the error message:

```
Incimpatible types
```

And when I hover over the line in the VBA Editor I see `Sant = True` in the tooltip.

I am surprised that some VBA code can stop working depending on the language version.

- What is the best way to make this statement functional independent of language?
- What other keywords in addition to "True" should I be wary of using in VBA?

Comment: Actually I am very puzzled by this problem. I have been using hosts of English language keywords in VBA including If, AND, Loop, For. This is the first time I have a problem when changing language version.

Comment: I tried changing 1 to True. I still get an error when running with Swedish settings in Excel 2013 and no error when running with English settings.

Comment: Try `If CBool(Sheets("Hämtningar").PivotTables("Hamtningar").PivotFields("strFacilityNo").PivotItems(i).Visible) = True Then`

Comment: That works! Feel free to post it as a solution. It would be great if you can understand why that works. My head still can't figure out why the original statement didn't work.

Comment: Glad to help :)  I'll try to find why and will edit my answer.  I'm curious too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
If CBool(Sheets("Hämtningar").PivotTables("Hamtningar").PivotFields("strFacilityNo"‌​).PivotItems(i).Visible) = True Then
```

I don't really know why but what I know is sometimes it does it with my Excel too (French) and sometimes not.  That is the way I correct it when it happens :)